# two forms of chiral molecule

Tags: chemfig, draw, chemistry

I need to draw a chiral molecule with CHEMFIG in two forms, one with the branches to the left and the other with the branches to the right.
the shape with the branches to the right is easy, but with the branches to the left I only got bad results.
How to draw a good structure for the molecule with the branches to the left?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, have you tried anything o have you read the documentation here? http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/372127/108724

Comment: Or see [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/514207/108724).

Comment: and for a quick review on package: see [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Chemical_Graphics).

Comment: Thanks very much!  The EDTA molecule have the information I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer. just a hint!!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\chemfig{C(-[:60]CH_2CH_2CH_3)(-[:180]@{Br}Br)(<[:280]CH_2CH_3)(<:[:320]CH_3)}
\chemmove{
    \draw[red,latex-](Br) ..controls +(70:4mm) and +(90:10mm) .. ($(Br)+(0.5,0.05)$);
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: warning: the place of two of them are not correct!!